# Unix AWK command - multiple character as a single delimiter

Tags: linux, unix, awk, terminal, delimiter

I am trying to use two data pipeline, `||` , as delimiter in AWK command. But I am unable to do it. I have a file in which I have to consider two data pipeline as delimiter, just like considering TAB or COMMA as delimiter.

Comment: Edit your question to include some sample input and expected output and what you have tried so far.

Comment: The solution is `awk -F'[|][|]' ....` . Thank You

Comment: ITYM **A** solution is.... Since you didn't post sample input and expected output and what you have tried so far that's the only answer you got - that doesn't mean it's the best one or even the right one for your real problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tell awk to interpret the | literally with `[]`:

```
awk -F'[|][|]' ...
```

Example:

```
» echo "1 || 2" | awk -F'[|][|]' '{ print $2 }'
2
```

Comment: You're welcome ;) please, don't forget to mark the thread as answered. Happy coding!